# C++ Socket Doesn't Finish Sending Data For Longer Message

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I have a function in which I am trying to send a message of 205453 bytes. The function below sends output until 143080 bytes and then the send(..) call returns -1 size_sent bytes 3 times in a row at which point it times out.

I have a python test client that is receiving the message in a while loop. It makes two calls and receives the 143080 bytes but it doesn't finish receiving the message.

I thought that it might be a timeout issue, so I disabled the C++ socket timeout but that didn't help.

```
setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDTIMEO,(const char*)&time_val_struct,sizeof(time_val_struct));`
```

C++ FUNCTION IS BELOW:

```
size_t network::send_full_msg(int sock_fd, char *write_buf, size_t write_buf_length, std::chrono::microseconds timeout)
{
    debug_log log("network_interface", "send_full_msg");
    try{

        

        log.msg("Preparing to send an entire message through. msg size is...." + to_string(write_buf_length));

        const size_t chunk_size = 16000;        //will read 16000 bytes at a time
        fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); //makes the socket nonblocking

        log.msg("Set socket non blocking..." + to_string(write_buf_length));

        struct timeval time_val_struct;
        time_val_struct.tv_sec = 0;
        time_val_struct.tv_usec = 0;
        setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDTIMEO,(const char*)&time_val_struct,sizeof(time_val_struct));
        log.msg("Turned off socket timeout..." + to_string(write_buf_length));


        size_t pos_in_buf = 0; //starts at 0 and is incremented to write to the right location
        ssize_t size_sent = 0; //the size of the values obtained from a recv

        int num_neg_count=0;
        auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        while (pos_in_buf < write_buf_length)
        {
            auto current_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(current_time - start_time);

            //cout << "Duration: " << duration.count() << endl;
            //cout << "Timeout: " << timeout.count() << endl;

            if (duration > timeout || num_neg_count>3) //timeout or 3 consecutive failed writes
            {
                log.msg("Timeout exceeded");
                break;
            }

            //remaining buf size is the total buf length minus the position (plus 1?)
            size_t remaining_buf_size = write_buf_length - pos_in_buf;                                     //avoids a segmentation fault

            size_t bytes_to_write = remaining_buf_size > chunk_size ? chunk_size : remaining_buf_size; //works to prevent a segmentation fault
            size_sent = send(sock_fd, write_buf+pos_in_buf, bytes_to_write, 0);

            log.msg("Sent bytes..." + to_string(size_sent));
            log.msg("Pos in buf..." + to_string(pos_in_buf));
            log.msg("Bytes to write..." + to_string(bytes_to_write));
            
            // log.msg("size_recv: " + to_string(size_recv));
            // log.msg("bytes to read: " + to_string(bytes_to_read));

            if (size_sent < 0)
            {
                num_neg_count++; //if there are 3 consecutive failed writes we will quit
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(100)); //needs to wait to try and get more data
                continue;
            }else{
                num_neg_count = 0; //reset the failed writes
                pos_in_buf += size_sent;
            }

            //log.msg("Data received! Length: " + to_string(size_recv));
            
        }

        log.msg("Total data length sent was: " + to_string(pos_in_buf));
        if(pos_in_buf == 0)
            return -1; //error, no data received

        return pos_in_buf; //the full size of the message received
    }catch(exception &e){
        cout << " Exception in network socket " << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The C++ output reads as follows:

```
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Preparing to send an entire message through. msg size is....205453
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Set socket non blocking...205453
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Turned off socket timeout
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...0
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...32000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...48000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...64000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...80000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...96000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...112000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...15080
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...128000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...-1
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...143080
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...-1
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...143080
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...-1
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...143080
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Sent bytes...-1
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Pos in buf...143080
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Bytes to write...16000
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Timeout exceeded
[ network_interface/send_full_msg ] Total data length sent was: 143080
```

I have tried to change the socket timeout, I also tried changing the size of the bytes being sent from 8000 bytes and 16000 bytes.

The output shows that it is sending the first 16000 bytes x 8 and then a 9th time it sends only 15080 bytes. This is strange because it should be sending another 16000 bytes again.

I checked to see if the input write_buf could have a problem, but is created from a string variable like so:

```
send_full_msg(client_fd, const_char<char*>(response.c_str()), response.length(), chrono::microseconds((int)5e6);
```

Also, if I resend the message even if the size changes to 207801, it always only sends 143080 bytes.

Comment: Call [`perror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) to get more information on why the `send` when it fails.

Comment: You specify the timeout to be 5 seconds. If it is not possible to send 200k bytes in that period of time, then either something is blocking the transmission or since you have a nonblocking socket `num_neg_count` increases rapidly to cause the break. Test if you have a 'real' timeout or the counter hits the threshold.

Comment: Please try commenting out the line that makes the socket non-blocking.

Comment: If `send` returns -1 it means there was an error. What was the error? If you don't know, then look up the `send` function and see how to find out what the error was

Comment: I tried perror(..) and it says "Resource temporarily unavailable". The python client that is receiving it gets 16000 bytes at a time and prints out that it got 143080 and is then waiting in a while loop for the rest of the data. Every single time it only sends that number of bytes. I would expect slight differences if I change for example the buffer size etc.

Comment: Your sender is controlled by the receiver's window size, not the send buffer size or the MTU.  Coping correctly with `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` is a basic necessity for sending with non-blocking sockets.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem using select(..)**

```
size_t network::send_full_msg(int sock_fd, char *write_buf, size_t write_buf_length, std::chrono::microseconds timeout) {
    debug_log log("network_interface", "send_full_msg");
    try{

        fd_set set;
        struct timeval socktimeout;
        int rv;
        FD_ZERO(&set); /* clear the set */
        FD_SET(sock_fd, &set); /* add our file descriptor to the set */

        socktimeout.tv_sec = std_thread_timeout_microseconds/1000000;
        socktimeout.tv_usec = 0;


        log.msg("Preparing to send an entire message through. msg size is...." + to_string(write_buf_length));

        const size_t chunk_size = 16000;        //will read 16000 bytes at a time
        //fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); //makes the socket nonblocking

        //log.msg("Set socket non blocking..." + to_string(write_buf_length));

        //struct timeval time_val_struct;
        //time_val_struct.tv_sec = 0;
        //time_val_struct.tv_usec = 0;
        //setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDTIMEO,(const char*)&time_val_struct,sizeof(time_val_struct));
        //log.msg("Turned off socket timeout");


        size_t pos_in_buf = 0; //starts at 0 and is incremented to write to the right location
        ssize_t size_sent = 0; //the size of the values obtained from a recv

        int num_neg_count=0;
        auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        log.msg("Entering loop non block on write...");



        while (pos_in_buf < write_buf_length)
        {
            auto current_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(current_time - start_time);


            rv = select(sock_fd + 1, NULL, &set, NULL, &socktimeout);
            if(rv==0){
                log.msg("Select timeout...num neg count is: " + to_string(num_neg_count));
                //timeout
                num_neg_count++;
                if(num_neg_count > 3){ //three timeouts in a row
                    return pos_in_buf == 0 ? -1 : pos_in_buf;
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if(rv==-1){
                //do nothing if this hits the timeout it will break out
                log.msg("Select error...num neg count is: " + to_string(num_neg_count));
            }
            else{
                //there is data to be handled
                log.msg("Select is saying socket is available for sending...");
                //remaining buf size is the total buf length minus the position (plus 1?)
                size_t remaining_buf_size = write_buf_length - pos_in_buf;                                     //avoids a segmentation fault

                size_t bytes_to_write = remaining_buf_size > chunk_size ? chunk_size : remaining_buf_size; //works to prevent a segmentation fault
                size_sent = send(sock_fd, write_buf+pos_in_buf, bytes_to_write, 0);

                log.msg("Sent bytes..." + to_string(size_sent));
                log.msg("Pos in buf..." + to_string(pos_in_buf));
                log.msg("Bytes to write..." + to_string(bytes_to_write));
                log.msg("Remaining buf size..." + to_string(remaining_buf_size));
                
                // log.msg("size_recv: " + to_string(size_recv));
                // log.msg("bytes to read: " + to_string(bytes_to_read));

                if (size_sent < 0)
                {
                    perror("Socket send returned -1");
                    num_neg_count++; //if there are 3 consecutive failed writes we will quit
                    //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(100)); //needs to wait to try and get more data
                    continue;
                }else{
                    num_neg_count = 0; //reset the failed writes
                    pos_in_buf += size_sent;
                }

                //log.msg("Data received! Length: " + to_string(size_recv));

            }

            //cout << "Duration: " << duration.count() << endl;
            //cout << "Timeout: " << timeout.count() << endl;

            if (duration > timeout || num_neg_count>3) //timeout or 3 consecutive failed writes
            {
                log.msg("Timeout exceeded");
                break;
            }


            
        }

        log.msg("Total data length sent was: " + to_string(pos_in_buf));
        if(pos_in_buf == 0)
            return -1; //error, no data received

        return pos_in_buf; //the full size of the message received
    }catch(exception &e){
        cout << " Exception in network socket " << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    } }
```

Comment: Your error handling code is still actually wrong, you should check whether `errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK` and deal with those differently to other errors.